# History of Path algebras

Tags: graph-theory, reference-request, math-history

I want some references that point the inventor of Path algebras and history/evolution of these algebras from the first idea. If possible.

I tried to search in many different places, but all times, the route stops at Gabriel.

Thanks.

Comment: You might also ask https://hsm.stackexchange.com/ , the history of science & math SE.